# Stateful server versus stateless server?

Tags: web-services, request, client, state

I understand the basic differences between the two but specifically I was wondering, can you pass arguments to both or to just the stateless server? Also, can you use caching to improve the performance of a stateless server?

Comment: And does the stateless server require passing arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass arguments to both stateless and statefull web-services (statefull services would be rather pointless without). For example you can use statefull services to implement a shopping cart where one method just adds a single item to the cart, the server already knowing what other items you have. You can use HTTP-Session to implement this.

[An example for JAX-WS on Weblogic is described here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24965/stateful.htm)

Caching is a wholly different issue, and it depends a lot on what you would like to cache. But in general, yes, it's possible to cache stateless services.